Are there any theoretical reasons why we cannot measure the position of a particle with zero error?
In experimental laboratories, every measurement of the position of a particle always returns an error, which can be very small, but is never zero.
Is this because our measuring instruments are imperfect, or are there theoretical reasons that can be derived from the standard postulates of QM?
For example, from a theoretical point of view, in the special theory of relativity a body with mass cannot move at the speed of light because this would require infinite energy.
Some of my reasoning makes me suppose that the standard postulates of QM imply that measuring the position with zero error requires infinite energy.
Could this be the theoretical reason why it is not possible to make a measurement of the position with zero error?

Yes. It's exactly the case. As per particle relativistic kinetic energy uncertainty $$ \Delta K={\sqrt {(\Delta p{\textrm {c}})^{2}+\left(m_{0}{\textrm {c}}^{2}\right)^{2}}}-m_{0}c^{2} $$ it grows to infinity as particle position uncertainty approaches zero. Since no particle can have infinite energy OR momentum, it's forbidden.

You don't even need to dive into quantum mechanics for this. Every measurement you will ever do will be of statistical nature and therefore will always suffer from shot noise. You need infinitely many data points to reach zero error. Of course on top of that you have quantum mechanical uncertainty etc.

This might help - The more general uncertainty principle, regarding Fourier transforms

You should ask another question about why using the infinite energy argument as the reason $c$ is unreachable is detrimental to new students' understanding of relativity.

You should be more precise about your understanding of zero. If you mean "there is an uncertainty/error range below which our measurements cannot go" (i.e. we cannot get closer to the true value than some delta no matter the method and effort) then that's probably false (not sure whether there is an underlying granularity of the universe around the Planck length or something? Maybe somebody can chime in here.) If you mean "why can we not measure continuous values  with infinite precision?" then the question basically answers itself.

Thanks @Peter-ReinstateMonica. My question is: "why can we not measure continuous values with infinite precision?".
I seem to conclude that, as you confirm, it is impossible to measure a continuous quantity with infinite precision and I understand that there are several reasons: 1 See Ján Lalinský's answer; 2 It would require an energy that tends to infinity; 3 the wave function cannot collapse on a Dirac delta.

Short version: There is no particle and it doesn't have a position. :-)

@R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE That is not true, electrons are massive point particles and approximate representations of their trajectories can be obtained from particle detectors. Charged particle tracks can be obtained from vapor/bubble chamber or modern particle detectors based on CCD or CMOS chips.

@JánLalinský: It's an excitation in a quantum field, which does not "have" a position, but can be observed at a position. The fact that "particle" is a simplified model without fundamental reality is one good reason (among many) you can't have an exact measurement of it.

@R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE No, that is just how the field-centric view of the theory looks on experiments with particles. It works well for EM field. Other viewpoints have particles as primary, and fields as auxiliary mathematics, this works well for fermions. But both particles and excited quantum fields are really just our simplified models without fundamental reality.

@JánLalinský: There is no possible theory in which there is such a thing as a particle which "has a position" except non-local-hidden-variable theories.

@R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE that is not what I disagree with. Particle has property position when the position is prepared by experiment, e.g. when it is detected in particle detector.

Continuous variables can't be measured with zero error in principle, already due to them being real numbers, nothing to do with quantum theory. It would take infinite number of digits to write down such precise measurement result, which is not possible in reality.
In a world where position is a discrete variable (integer number), we can think of the possibility that such position could be measured (meaning the associated quantum state could be prepared) with zero error.
Discrete variables can be measured (really, quantum state prepared) with zero error. For example, spin projection - it is either up or down (relative to magnetic field of the SG magnet).

I had never read a statement like that, but it seems to me a very reasonable and extremely useful reflection. Thank you.

@GiovanniMastrogiovanni you're welcome. Also, notice position operator in quantum theory has no normalizable eigenstates, all normalizable psi functions have non-zero width. Thus quantum theory formalism satisfies this constraint of impossibility of precise results of measurements of continuous variables.

Thanks Ján Lalinský. What you say is absolutely true. From a mathematical point of view, the postulates of QM seem to show that it is impossible to measure the position with zero error, this would lead to an absurdity: the wave function would collapse becoming a Dirac delta function that cannot represent a physical state.
My reasoning seems to arrive at the same result starting from physical considerations. So the picture seems absolutely coherent.

@GiovanniMastrogiovanni yes, at least here in this small patch, quantum theory is consistent with the usual knowledge and with itself. If only it was so clear and consistent everywhere.

Why would you assume that an exact measurement must be written in decimal form? Why wouldn't it be possible for you to measure (say) a position of exactly $\sqrt{2}$? Am I misunderstanding your first paragraph?

@MPV result of measurement in physics is always a rational number ( or a pair of those), irrational numbers can be obtained from measurement only via mathematical operation. How would you look at a meter or a clock and read $\sqrt{2}$ meters/seconds?

@JánLalinský, Say for instance my meter stick has marks at $\sqrt 2,$m, $2 \sqrt 2,$m, $3 \sqrt 2,$m, etc. instead of $1,$m, $2,$m, $3,$m. If you're not convinced by that, what if I measure distance by rolling a $1,$m diameter wheel along the ground, and marking every $\pi,$m?

@Vaelus Your meter stick is for measuring in a new system of units, where the standard (unit) of length $l_0$ has length (in meters) $\sqrt{2}$ and result of any measurement in this system will be integer number of $l_0$. Only when you express it in meters, the result will be irrational. Thus to get an irrational number out of the measurement, you have to take the measured number of marks (integer) and multiply it by irrational number defining values in meters, here $\sqrt{2}$. This won't happen if you use only the unit of the stick. The same argument works for points separated by $\pi$ m.

@Vaelus Also, any measurement of length has error somewhere between zero and $l_0/2+r$, where $l_0$ is the unit used to mark the stick and $r$ is error of reading (usually, smaller than $l_0$); and already since $l_0$ is finite, the measurement has always non-zero upper bound of error. Thus using a meter stick where $l_0$ is irrational in meters won't help us get infinitely precise measurement.

I'm not sure this is a fully satisfying answer. For any observable I could ask, for example, whether you can design a series $n={1,2,...}$ of experiments to measure that observable with precision ${1/2^n}.$ Then there's a reasonable question as to whether the possibility to 'measure zero' is in this sense is different between classical and quantum theories. This is a totally reasonable set of physical data to think about.

@Vaelus I'd be interested to know how your  $\sqrt{2}$ meter measuring stick was marked out. If we have a measuring stick that is exact in metres (not sure how we do that, either), we can construct  $\sqrt{2}$ easily, but we still need to mark the stick exactly (I'm not sure how to do that either). But what if the "correct" measurement is a multiple of  $\sqrt{3}$? Or a solution of an irreducible quintic, such as $2x^5-10x+5=0$? Won't you need an infinite number of specialized measuring sticks?

@SethK for any $n$ in your series, error is non-zero. Your question about measuring zero is unclear (did you mean measuring with zero error?),
but maybe it should be asked as a new question.

@SimonCrase I think you got it - even if we label marks $n\sqrt{2}$ m,$n=1,2,...$, this does not give us a way to measure with zero error. One particular measurement may be denoted as $\sqrt{2}$ meters, but this measurement is still loaded with error close to half the spacing between the marks.

Any symbolic scheme you can use to precisely represent a number, be it digits, roots (like on this hypothetical ruler), fractions/decimals, or even series, is fundamentally an integer.  The integers are merely countably infinite, while the reals are uncountably so.  So if position is on a continuous real distribution, then the odds of it matching any real number which may be symbolically depicted is basically nothing.

In quantum mechanics the two variables
(i) position x and
(ii) momentum are "correlated" in the sense that if we multiply their uncertainties, they have to exceed a certain number. This is called Heisenberg uncertainty principle. You will find many webpages describing this principle, although it is also through that it does not make sense from a classical perspective.
Note that Heisenberg does not set a "smallest allowed uncertainty" to the position measurement. It only demands that if you know the position of a (quantum) particle extremely well, you don't know much about its momentum.

well, you can know its average momentum, which may well be 0. But the uncertainty is large. This is not just a nit point, because ignoring it leads to classical thinking and the misleading analogy where momentum "blurs" the measurement--and the is just wrong.

Thanks Semoi. Heisenberg's principle requires that having a measurement of x with an increasingly smaller "error" (SigmaX of the x distribution), also implies having a measurement of p with an increasingly larger "error" (SigmaP of the p distribution). SigmaP increasingly larger implies an increasingly larger average energy.
So if SigmaX tends to zero, then SigmaP tends to infinity and the average energy tends to infinity as well.
This makes me think that SigmaX cannot become zero, even if it can become extremely small.
What could be wrong with my reasoning?
Thanks.

You might try a thought experiment: how can I measure the position of a particle with minimal (ideally zero) error? This is how my sixth form physics teacher introduced Heisenberg's uncertainty principle: he suggested just looking at the particle to see where it was. Unfortunately you need photons to do that, and they have momentum, which disturbs the particle...I know, let's try radio waves instead! Oh, photons again...
BTW Heisenberg based his quantum mechanics principal that your theory should not mention things that you can't measure, e.g. if you cannot measure the position of an electron without a certain error, your theory should not talk about the position,

Unfortunately, that thought experiment, while commonly used, isn't actually what's going on in the uncertainty principle. What you're talking about is the observer effect, but as JEB mentioned in a comment on Semoi's answer, the uncertainty in measuring two complementary variables like position and momentum is innate to QM even without that factor. Even with a hypothetical perfect measuring device that doesn't interact with the object being measured in any way, there would still exist correlated uncertainty in position and momentum.

@Idran You are, of course, correct about the uncertainty principle, but I think the thought experiment would help the OP answer his own question. How can one measure something with zero error? Surely merely looking at something doesn't  affect it-except it does. I wonder about astronomy: we don't need to bombard starts with photons to observe them, but I do need to measure the orientation of the telescope, so I need to bombard the scale with photons...

The Planck length is hypothesised as the minimal length measurement, so we shouldn't expect to measure the position of an electron with uncertainty much smaller than this value.

OP asked about "a particle", not an electron. Trying to confine an electron to a region smaller than its Compton wavelength is not possible.

Thanks Mozibur Ullah. This is absolutely true if one also takes into account general relativity. I am trying to understand the consequences of the standard postulates of non-relativistic quantum mechanics, so I do not take into account the concept of Palck length.

@JEB: I considered writing "a particle" first, and then decided that using an electron would make what I was writing more concrete.

@GiovanniMastrogiovanni Mastrogiovanni: The notion of a Planck length does not rely on GR. Its an independent notion and relies on the gravitational constant $G$ but this constant is established in Newtonian physics.

@JEB: The Compton wavelength of an electron is the length at which QM properties become visible. I think its quite possible that an electron wavelength could be made shorter so long as the uncertainty principle is satisfied.

according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_wavelength, $\lambda_C$ is the position uncertainty at which the energy associated with momentum uncertainty exceed $2m_ec^2$, so that QED kicks in and $e^+e^-$ pairs are made, and then your electron loses its identity as "the" electron you're trying to pin down. Which I think qualifies as a "theoretical reason" per OP's question.

@JEB: Sure, this works for an electron but as you pointed out the OP asked about a particle not just electrons. Now the Compton wavelength is inversely proportional to mass and there are heavier particles than the electron, for example the W bosons. The Planck length is postulated as the minimal theoretical distance that can be probed by a particle, so this should set a maximal mass for a particle.
